# Pass parameter to validateWrite method in table

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

I'm calling validateWrite table method from class and I need to pass boolean parameter to it
in order to skip one of the check methods called inside validateWrite,
but it's not possible, because validateWrite method of table can't be overridden.
Is there any way to pass this parameter or to skip the check inside thos method?
Please advise.

Comment: Is the check you want to skip in the validateWrite itself or is it called from there?

Comment: The check is called from validateWrite, and inside validateWrite is the condition ret = ret && check(), this check should be skipped

Comment: If you see a `validateWrite()` method, it's by definition overridden from `xRecord.validateWrite()`. I'm pretty sure you can just add a parameter, but it needs a **default**, so kernel calls won't fail. A sample declaration is `public boolean validateWrite(boolean _skipWhatever = false)`. Have you tried that?

Comment: thanks a lot! I passed the parameter with default value and it works! I wish I could mark a comment above as an answer

Comment: @julia I made my comment an answer, glad I could help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you see a `validateWrite()` method, it's by definition overridden from `xRecord.validateWrite()`. I'm pretty sure you can just add a parameter, but it needs a default, so kernel calls won't fail. A sample declaration is:

> `public boolean validateWrite(boolean _skipWhatever = false)`